# Android developer account with someone else credit card

Tags: android

I am trying to sign up for an Android developer account, costs $25. I am without a credit card for time being. I will get a credit card in 2-3 weeks but cannot wait that long. So would it be possible to pay it now from someone else i.e friends credit card and change credit card information later? It seems hard to believe Google would require the credit card for anything more than payment but from what I can tell they register the developer side forever under the credit card owner. Someone correct me if I'm wrong before I waste $25 or bind someone else to my developer account by accident.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I had the exact same issue. Used my mothers creditcard initially. Afterwards you can add a new card and make that your default card. After which you can remove the old creditcard.

Note: that they will donate a random amount of money (say 16 cents) which is used to verify your account

Comment: are u sure that Google will not bind the account to the credit card owner as I go to create the account, it accepts my payment then brings me to a screen with this message: "I agree and I am willing to associate my credit card and account registration above with the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement." The name in the box that appears is the name of my friend(credit card owner) not myself. From what I can tell then the developer account will be forever linked to that person and not me even though it is my google account. Is this correct?

Comment: @Haris AFAIK, the credit card is associated with the Wallet account but can be removed later. However, I don't know how it affects one's Play Developer Console account. I have the same problem, not having a correct card type. I'm concerned about, after having a friend helping me out and then removing his card,  my Dev Console account being disabled and my $25 being thrown out of the window for nothing in exchange. That'd be painful...